# Dynamic layouts in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swift4

I am writing an app that has various layouts for an 'event'. The required labels and TextFields are provided through an API call to a web service.

Is there any way, either by code or 3rd party framework, to dynamically create a view layout like this?

I have looked at Eureka which looks like it will do half of what is required. However, I do not use storyboards and I need other controls on in the view so I need to add a Eureka form as a subview which I can't get to work. Also, Eureka is based on TableView and I need the flexibility to layout some textfields side-by-side.

Comment: using `UIStackView`, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check [**Neon**](https://github.com/mamaral/Neon). It offers dynamic layout without springs and struts or programatic constraints.
I found another [**Layout**](https://github.com/schibsted/layout) library for implementing iOS user interfaces using runtime-evaluated expressions for layout and XML template files.

Comment: Neon looks pretty much perfect. Thanks

Comment: Anytime Tony :)